# Cannot read Resource from /static folder in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Given a Spring Boot Maven Project with this structure:

```
src
  main
    resources
      static
        file.txt
```

This gets packaged into a jar file:

```
static
  file.txt
```

I have tried the following ways to try to read file.txt:

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("file.txt");
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("/file.txt");
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("static/file.txt");
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("/static/file.txt");
```

None of these work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a resource. Packaged inside a jar file. A `File` represents a path on the file system. So it can't represent an entry of a jar file.

Use `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/static/file.txt")`. That uses the class loader, and thus loads resources from all the directories and jar files in the classpath.

Comment: My first approach was to use servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/static/file.txt") which does not work. But using your approach does. Any idea why?

Comment: Add to add to the mystery, in a non-Boot Spring MVC app, servletContext works, but the class loader does not.